# Using function object in stl algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

When trying to use a conditional `copy_if` algorithm to copy only the values that are lower than mean of values in a vector into another vector, I hit a snag with my function object:

```
struct Lower_than_mean
{
private:
    double mean;
    vector<double>d1;
public:
    Lower_than_mean(vector<double>a)
        :d1{a}
    {
        double sum = accumulate(d1.begin(), d1.end(), 0.0);
        mean = sum / (d1.size());
    }
    bool operator()(double& x)
    {
        return x < mean;
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<double>vd{ 3.4,5.6, 7, 3,4,5.6,9,2 };
    vector<double>vd2(vd.size());

    copy_if(vd.begin(), vd.end(), vd2, Lower_than_mean(vd));

}
```

What is the right way of going about this?

Comment: What sort of "snag" do you hit?

Comment: Copying and holding entire vector, when you use just the mean seems like a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `vd` instead of `vd.begin()` in the call to `std::copy_if`.

But, seriously, you didn't bother to even read your compiler output...

Also, like @zch suggests - your approach doesn't make sense: Don't keep re-calculating the mean again and again. Instead, calculate it once, and then your function becomes as simple `[mean](double x) { return x < mean; }` lambda.

Comment: ahh thanks!!... I don't know how I missed the vd.begin() part.. Then the part where i copy the vector is just cos the size won't be too large to make any big effect. And I think the mean being in the function object can allow me to use the Lower_than_mean function for other vector<double> containers...or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Just create another lambda-closure at different locations with a different precalculated mean.